# Filter for google cloud build with a given commit_sha

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to list Google Cloud builds and filter by `source.repo.commit_sha` as specified in the [Viewing build results](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results#filtering_build_results_using_queries) documentation, but my list is coming back with no items. I am using the following command:

```
gcloud builds list --filter "source.repo.commit_sha='${LONG_COMMIT_SHA}'"
```

I have tried using the short commit and the long commit SHA-1, but I am not getting any results. The SHA-1 value is the value from the commit that was pushed to github. I am using a trigger to initiate the build, the trigger works correctly.

I have search the internet for information about filtering with a given commit SHA-1, but I have been unable to find any useful information.

Can someone please help with a command to filter with a given commit SHA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like an Gcloud SDK issue I found a error report on this [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/155681468) about similar behavior with the filters.

I think that is better continue in the public issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will post additional information on the thread you linked here

Comment: if this is useful, please consider mark this answer as valid and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

While this issue still remains unresolved, there is a somewhat hacky way to perform commit sha filtering. Assuming that your builds are invoked by triggers, a fair amount of build execution information will be exposed through built-in substitutions. Notably this includes commit sha & branch name. See below link for full list of builtin substitutions. Even if you do not currently use triggers and just manually launch your builds through the CLI, you can still create a trigger and just manually launch it through the UI to also expose these builtins.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

You can then create a new tag for your builds, and just use the exposed branch built in substitution for this tag name. See about halfway down the below link for adding tags to your cloudbuild file.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/view-build-results#filtering_build_results_using_queries

You can then filter on tag being set to a specific commit sha / branch name